# MIN() results are not correct

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to find the the lowest street address number for every street in my area.  My results return the wrong value, so I need help understanding why it's returning the wrong value and how to correct it so I get the desired results.

I'm using SQLServer 2012

**TABLE (A) columns:**

```
ZONE_NUMBER (int, null),
Street_NUMBER (char(10), null),
Street_Name (varchar(255), not null),
Street_Type (char(5), null)
```

**TABLE (A) values:**

```
ZONE_NUMBER | STREET_NUM | STREET_NAME | STREET TYPE |
13             1502         COTTONWOOD    DR
13             1544         COTTONWOOD    DR
13             1564         COTTONWOOD    DR
13             720          COTTONWOOD    DR
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
   zone_number,
   min(street_number) as street_number
FROM
   A
GROUP by ZONE_NUMBER
```

**Expected Results:**

```
ZONE_NUMBER | STREET_NUMBER
13            720
```

**Actual Results:**

```
ZONE_NUMBER | STREET_NUMBER
13            1502
```

If I change from min() to max(), I get my desired results:

```
ZONE_NUMBER | STREET_NUMBER
13            720
```

Why?  Is there something I'm missing?

Also, if '0' Street_number had it's own record, how can I skip '0' and get the next lowest result?

Thanks for any considerations for answering this problem.

Comment: well, `STREET_NUMBER` is a char data type, so the order is alphabetically, and `'1502'` is smaller than `'720'` because `'1'` comes before than `'7'`. If there's always gonna be numbers, either use a numeric data type, or convert the result to one before using `MIN` or `MAX`

Comment: That's what the issue was!  Thanks for spotting that and answering so quickly.

Comment: This is a really common and nasty problem. I think you need to seriously consider why you want to sort these values, because in the real world the property addresses are rarely ordered conveniently. Address will also contains letters and characters for apartments and units. (10A and 10B 2/10 etc). A few houses near me are good examples. There is a 98B and 2/98B. The property behind me is 100E which comes before 100 which is the next house along the road, and there is no 100 B,C or D.

Comment: You may wish to rename your question "how to sort addresses"

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using 2012, you can use [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) as Lamak alluded to if you can't change the street number data type. Note, if you have something other an an `INT` in this column, then your results will not contain these rows

```
SELECT 
   zone_number,
   min(try_convert(int,street_number)) as street_number
FROM
   A
GROUP by ZONE_NUMBER
```